# How to combine Input together with string?

Tags: batch-file

Below is my Batch File codes.
I am trying to combine Input together with string.
Using below codes only return second Echo as result.

```
@echo off
set Output="%USERPROFILE%\desktop"
set /p PWD=Key Id Your SWTAT Password : 
Echo Echo %PWD% | clip >>SWTAT.bat 
Echo Start "" http://swtat.somesite.com/LogOn.aspx >>SWTAT.bat
```

Output i am trying to get is as below.
Assume Input is "Password".

```
Password | clip
Start "" http://swtat.somesite.com/LogOn.aspx
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the pipe in order to prevent your command to be redirected.

Also `Echo Echo %PWD% ^| clip >>SWTAT.bat` will output the second `Echo` which seems you do not want to.

So:

```
@echo off
set Output="%USERPROFILE%\desktop"
set /p PWD=Key Id Your SWTAT Password : 
Echo %PWD% ^| clip >>SWTAT.bat 
Echo Start "" http://swtat.somesite.com/LogOn.aspx >>SWTAT.bat
```